# How to define many struct elements in one go?

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

```
struct something
{
    int a;
    int b;

} this[10] = {1,2};
```

This bit of code is creating 10 elements with such a struct. But, only the first element a,b ints are set to 1,2.

Can we modify this code to set all 10 elements with these values?

Comment: Asks question, then shifts ground. Unclear what's being asked. Vote to close on that basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct something
{
    int a;
    int b;

} this[10] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10},{11,12},{13,14},{15,16},{17,18},{19,20}};
```

Or did you mean:

```
struct something
{
    int a;
    int b;
} this[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) this[i] = {1,2};
```

Comment: Nope, I don't mean increment the values, and also not typing them all out individually since it would be a pain on large set of 100 elements.

Comment: "Nope" yourself. Express your question more clearly. I modified "this code" to set all 10 elements, which is what you asked for. The 1,2,3,4 was just a kind of joke; I don't care what the values _are_, I'm just showing you the notation. If your question wasn't about the notation, then edit it to clarify what it _is_ about, since, as you can see, other people think I'm answering the question you asked.

Comment: @louisinhongkong Also, naming a variable "this" is a terrible idea for obvious reasons.

Comment: @matt wasn't trying to be rude so not sure why you're flying off the rails here. I did say "set all 10 elements with these values." which i think is pretty clear but nevermind, thanks for your comprehensive answer anyways.